# Get selected text in a Dash application

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to receive text selected by the user when the user presses a button.

The background is:

I’d like to create an app to label text sequences (for an NLP application). The user would:

- Look at the presented text
- Select a piece of text
- Press a button to confirm selection
- Repeat

So, once the user presses a button, I would like to receive the currently selected text as input.

Is that possible with Dash? In Dash, you can attach callbacks to component properties. So, I was looking for a property that captures the text selection. Unfortunately, `html.Div`, `html.P`, or `html.Span` don't have it. `dcc.Input` has it but it is only limited to one line and I need to show a multi-line text. And `dcc.Textarea` while not being limited to one line, again, doesn't have such a property.

Comment: You can easily do this with dash or [panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/)

Comment: That makes me optimistic :) But how? I didn't find a way to do that with Dash. I edited the questions adding my findings so far.

Comment: I've the feeling that panel would be a better tool in this case. Given you already have a bullet list you can start building your project.

Comment: Then this question is in risk to be closed cos it need more focus.

Comment: Just saying the very first point is described (here)[https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload]

Comment: I think the question is stated clearly. I don't see at all how the upload component can help me getting the selected text.

Comment: Would you like this to work as a web application with multiple users, or just with one computer and one user on same computer?

Comment: @Konstantinyes the question is stated clearly but it contains multiple questions in one. Which is the "Need more focus" option to close a question. Mine was just a friendly remark.

Comment: @np8 not sure if this is the case but you can eventually use [clientside-callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) here.

Comment: If you can not find a ready-made python solution, you could use for example [react-highlight](https://github.com/ydeshayes/react-highlight) and make your [own Dash component](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins).

Comment: @np8, ideally as a multi-user application. But does this have impact on the solution? I was already thinking that it might become necessary to create a custom component. Which would probably cost me days, as I have no experience with react.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution you can start from. Let's start with the code and an explanation will follow.

This is the python code:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
box_style = dict(border='1px solid', margin='15px', padding='10px')
app.layout = html.Div(id='wrapper', children=[
    html.P(id='selection-container', children='This text is selectable. Select here.', style=box_style),
    html.P(id='other-container', children='Selecting this text will not work.', style=box_style),
    dcc.Input(id='selection-target', value='', style=dict(display='none')),
    html.Button(id='submit', children='Submit selection'),
    html.P(id='callback-result', children=''),
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('callback-result', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('submit', 'n_clicks')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('selection-target', 'value')],)
def update_output(n_clicks, value):
    if value:
        return html.Span(f'Selected string: "{value}"', style=dict(color='green'))
    return html.Span('Nothing selected', style=dict(color='red'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Now some JavaScript. You need to put this in a JS file under a directory called "assets" (e.g. `assets/custom.js`; explained [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/static-assets)):

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var sel_str = sel.toString();
  var target_value = '';
  if (sel_str.length > 0) {
    var pid = sel.focusNode.parentNode.id;
    if (pid == 'selection-container') {
      target_value = sel_str;
    }
  }
  // Way to set value of React input
  var input = document.getElementById('selection-target');
  var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, target_value);
  var ev2 = new Event('input', {bubbles: true});
  input.dispatchEvent(ev2);

});
```

Now the explanation: the code creates two HTML P elements, one is selectable and the other is not. When selecting text in the selectable box and clicking the button, the selected text is shown in a third output P, via callback. This is achieved by updating the value of a hidden text input with the selected text (using a method compatible with the React framework). Clicking the button triggers a callback, which receives this value as a state. The hidden input can be changed to any other type of input, and I suppose a text area will work as well but I haven't tested it.

A couple of things to note: the JS event capturing is a bit quirky and far from complete. Capturing the document's "mouse up" event isn't ideal, and you should be able to think of a better way. Also, if you start your selection from the unselectable P and select backwards into the selectable P, the event will get triggered, so you need to take care of that as well.

Hope this helps. Please update us with the solution you chose eventually.

Comment: Unfortunately, when you wrote the answer I was already half way through creating a custom Dash component. Now I'm done and will post the result maybe tomorrow, so that others can use it as well. It turned out to be easier than expected with the excellent documentation and example component repo that @np8 posted in his or her comment.

Comment: @Konstantin Can you please post your solution (if possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using Dash-React integration, following [this](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins) and [this](https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate) guidelines, and using the following JavaScript code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  let timeout;

  return function () {
    const context = this, args = arguments;
    const later = () => {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    const callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}


export default class Highlightable extends Component {

  mouseEvent() {

    let text = '';

    if (window.getSelection) {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }

    if(!text || !text.length) {
      return false;
    }

    this.props.setProps({
      selected_text: text,
      selection_start: window.getSelection().anchorOffset,
    })
  }

  onMouseUp(event) {
    debounce(() => {
      if (this.doucleckicked) {
        this.doucleckicked = false;
        this.dismissMouseUp++;
      } else if(this.dismissMouseUp > 0) {
        this.dismissMouseUp--;
      } else {
        this.mouseEvent.bind(this)();
      }
    }, 200).bind(this)();
  }

  onDoubleClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.doucleckicked = true;
    this.mouseEvent.bind(this)();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div id={this.props.id}
             style={{
               whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
               display: 'inline-block',
               verticalAlign: 'text-top',
               margin: '10px',
               width: this.props.width}}
             onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp.bind(this)}
             onDoubleClick={this.onDoubleClick.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
    );
  }
}

Highlightable.defaultProps = {};

Highlightable.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  width: PropTypes.string,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  selected_text: PropTypes.string,
  selection_start: PropTypes.number,
  selection_end: PropTypes.number,
  /**
   * Dash-assigned callback that should be called to report property changes
   * to Dash, to make them available for callbacks.
   */
  setProps: PropTypes.func
};
```